# Arithmetic precision problems with large numbers

Tags: python, precision

I am writing a program that handles numbers as large as `10 ** 100`, everything looks good when dealing with smaller numbers but when values get big I get these kind of problems:

```
>>> N = 615839386751705599129552248800733595745824820450766179696019084949158872160074326065170966642688
>>> ((N + 63453534345) / sqrt(2)) == (N / sqrt(2))
>>> True
```

Clearly the above comparision is false, why is this happening?

### Program code:

```
from math import *

def rec (n):
    r = sqrt (2)
    s = r + 2
    m = int (floor (n * r))
    j = int (floor (m / s))
    if j <= 1:
        return sum ([floor (r * i) for i in range (1, n + 1)])
    assert m >= s * j and j > 1, "Error: something went wrong"
    return m * (m + 1) / 2 - j * (j + 1) - rec (j)

print rec (1e100)
```

## Edit:

I don't think my question is a duplicate of the linked question above because the decimal points in `n, m and j` are not important to me and I am looking for a solution to avoid this precision issue.

Comment: Floating point numbers have limited precision. If the standard range is insufficient you must use write your own code, perhaps using modules like decimal to help you.

Comment: Python has arbitrary-precision _integers_ but not arbitrary-precision _real numbers_.  When you divide `N` and `N + 63453534345` by `sqrt(2)`, both are converted to IEEE double, which doesn't have enough precision to represent the difference.

Comment: Is there a way around this, I don't care about the decimals as I need these numbers floored eventually?

Comment: You need to compute square roots of 100 digits numbers? What other operations do you need to compute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: The module `decimal` is the standard module for higher (though obviously still finite) precision.

Comment: `sqrt(2)` is your problem. You can recast everything you do in terms of exact conditions involving integers. For example `a = floor(n*sqrt(2))` if and only if `a` is the largest integer satisfying the inequality `a**2 <= 2*n**2`, and such an `a` can be found with binary search (among other ways). The module `decimal` is probably less work than going this route. It can handle hundreds of decimal places with no problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can’t retain the precision you want while dividing by standard floating point numbers, so you should instead divide by a `Fraction`. The `Fraction` class in the `fractions` module lets you do exact rational arithmetic.

Of course, the square root of 2 is not rational. But if the error is less than one part in `10**100`, you’ll get the right result.

So, how to compute an approximation to `sqrt(2)` as a `Fraction`? There are several ways to do it, but one simple way is to compute the integer square root of `2 * 10**200`, which will be close to `sqrt(2) * 10**100`, then just make that the numerator and make `10**100` the denominator.

Here’s a little routine in Python 3 for integer square root.

```
def isqrt(n):
    lg = -1
    g = (1 >> n.bit_length() // 2) + 1
    while abs(lg - g) > 1:
        lg = g
        g = (g + n//g) // 2
    while g * g > n:
        g -= 1
    return g
```

You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: Glad I could help :)